# Change tablet keyboard from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, web-applications

I developed web application which runs on tablets (I support safari and chrome browsers on iPad and android tablets).

When keyboard is opened, it hides most of the screen (landscape mode).

Is there any way to change its height?

Answer (score 0):

There are keyboards with diferent sizes, but it's up to the end user which one he/she uses (they have to be installed).

So this is out of your control.

What you can do is set the content type of a field, this will make it show numbers or letters.

You could reinvet a keyboard for your webapp, but users probably won't like it.